# empty cell on top of my dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

```
turnout = referendum_df[['Pct_Turnout','Region']]
result = turnout('Region').median()
result
```

it returns:

[image]

on the left side of the Pct_Turnout there is an empty cell and on the right of the region there is an empty cell how can I get rid of them.

Comment: This maybe a display issue where your index has a name but who can tell when you don't post raw data and code for others to reproduce. Anyway try `df.index.name = None`

Comment: you can use: `result.rename_axis(None)`